# Convert date value into three separate date parts (day, month, year)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three dropdown lists for day, month, and year respectively. I insert them in the database in one date column by combining the values and converting it to date. Now I have to retrieve them again into their respective dropdown lists.

```
DAY values(1~31)
Month values (Jan-Dec)
Year values (1990-2017)
```

I use this code when I insert them in the table:

```
userInfoDTO.Birthday = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dropMonth.SelectedValue, dropDay.SelectedValue, dropYear.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: How you are collecting the value from database? can you please share that code

Comment: MSDN links of [DateTime.Day](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day(v=vs.110).aspx), [DateTime.Month](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DateTime.Year](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: by using datareader. somehing like:
DateTime birthday = (DateTime) reader["Birthday"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DateTime birthDay; // initialize with the DateTime Field from database
dropMonth.SelectedValue = birthDay.Day;
dropDay.SelectedValue =birthDay.Month;
dropYear.SelectedValue = birthDay.Year;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the specific values from a DateTime type with `DateTime.Day`, `DateTime.Month` and `DateTime.Year`

Answer (score 1):

If your Month values are strings you can set `SelectedValue` like this:

```
dropDay.SelectedValue = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(birthDay.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

```
DateTime yourDOBCompleteDate; // get this from database
Month= yourDOBCompleteDate.Day;
Day=yourDOBCompleteDate.Month;
Year= yourDOBCompleteDate.Year;
```